# Using performSegue(with identifier...) transitions between two screens instead of one

Tags: swift, xcode

In my code I have this segue:

```
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapView) 
        locCoord = mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: mapView) 

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

        annotation.coordinate = locCoord!
        annotation.title = "latitude:" + String(format: "%0.02f", annotation.coordinate.latitude) + "& longitude:" + String(format: "%0.02f", annotation.coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.subtitle = "Loc of new bball court"


        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addCourtSegue", sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer.self)
    }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        let vc = segue.destination as! Newcourtviewcontroller
        vc.locCoord = self.locCoord
    }
```

Basically I have a MapKit set up on a screen and a gesture recognizer on top of the MapKit. Whenever a user taps a location on the map, it creates an annotation and performs a segue to go to another screen (the segue is set up from one view controller to the next view controller in the Storyboard and given an identification tag that I refer to in performSegue). However, when I open up the iOS simulator and try out the segue, it transitions between two screens (the intermediate screen is only visible for 0.5-1 seconds) when it should only transition to one screen. Look at the images below. I am insure why it is doing this because I only set up a segue in the storyboard to transition to one screen. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Second screen segue transitions to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSVL0.png)
[First/intermediate screen segue transitions to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08V8b.png)

Comment: Could you be able to describe things by "A","B","C"? (I know, that sounds dumb. But it helps to debug the actual issue.) For instance, you actually coded for `"addCourtSegue"`... so you haven't't really explained what other segue you've defined - much coded for. It's hard to actually duplicate your issue with what you've shown. Help us help you.

Comment: if two screens are showing id make sure you're not calling `performSegue` twice - random thought: `UILongPressGestureRecognizers` fire when you press down and when you press up, not sure what calls  `handleTap` ?